# How to break while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to find if a element in a list exists in a range where the list size is known and number of ranges is also known

I have tried a logic in python using a `while` loop

```
a[1]=[23,330,460]
r=[1,120,300,450,600]
```

and my range list are

- 1 to 100 for i=0
- 120 to 220 for i=1
- 300 to 400 for i=2
- 450 to 550 for i=3
- 600 t0 700 for i=4

`a[1]` has some values which is compared with the elements in range

`a[0]` is output got after checking

if `a[1]` is not in the range defined
`a[0]` must be 0,
else 1

```py
j=0 
for i in range(0,5):
    while j<3:
        l=list(range(r[i],r[i]+100))
        if a[1][j] in l:
            a[0].append(1)
            j=j+1
        else:
            a[0].append(0)
            j=j
```

I expect the output to be `a[0]=[1 0 1 1 0]`

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you define "a" initially.  From the look of things a[1][j] is never in l, hence you always go into your "else"

Comment: Please produce a [mre]

Comment: Your loop does probably live forever because you are only incrementing `j` in one branch of your conditional, so your `while`-criterion may just always be true.

Comment: Using `a` to contain both input and output in different cells is a very odd design. Perhaps rethink your data structures.

Comment: What is `i`? The index into the elements of `a[0]` and `a[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not change 'j' value in else since it executes first in this case,so it becomes infinite.

```
a=[[],[23,330,460]]
r=[1,120,300,450,600] 
for i in range(5):
    j=0 
    l=list(range(r[i],r[i]+100))
    while j<3:            
        if a[1][j] in l:
            a[0].append(1)
            break
        j=j+1
    else:
        a[0].append(0)

print(a[0])
#[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

**Using for**

```
a=[[],[23,330,460]]
r=[1,120,300,450,600] 
for i in range(5):
    l=list(range(r[i],r[i]+100))
    for j in a[1]:
        if j in l:
            a[0].append(1)
            break
    else:
        a[0].append(0)

print(a[0])
#[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

**Using any**

Updated as per [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438791) answer, range is not necessary

```
a=[[],[23,330,460]]
r=[1,120,300,450,600] 
for i in range(5):
    a[0].append(int(any(r[i]<=j<=r[i]+100 for j in a[1])))
print(a[0])
#[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list of 100 elements on each iteration over the loop is extremely inefficient and unidiomatic. I think you want simply

```
result = []
for pos, val in enumerate(a[1]):
    if r[pos] <= val <= r[pos]+100:
        comp = 1
    else:
        comp = 0
    result.append(comp)
```

or more succinctly with a list comprehension

```
result = [1 if r[pos] <= val <= r[pos]+100 else 0
    for pos, val in enumerate(a[1])]
```

If you want the value to be in `a[0]` then simply assign `a[0] = result` at the end; but really, this design is extremely dubious. I would suggest you keep two separate variables, or possibly refactor the input and output into a class if you need to keep them together.

Comment: I realize the first range is 1 to 100, not 0 to 100 or 1 to 101, so maybe refactor this to a special case, or maybe review your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you use another if: if the result is what you expect, keep going. If not, break.

```
result = []
for pos, val in enumerate(a[1]):
    if r[pos] <= val <= r[pos]+100:
        comp = 1
    else:
        if comp == 1 then 
        echo 'Well done'
         else break 0;


    result.append(comp)
```

Not pretty sure btw...